# Fieldset contents overflow in Firefox

Tags: css, overflow, fieldset

I am having a css issue with fieldset and wonder if you could help?

I have a fieldset with width smaller than its content div's width.

I want the fieldset to display a horizontal scroll bar as the content is too wide but it only works in IE's not Firefox.

Thanks in advance.

Eric

This is the html

```
<fieldset style=" width:150px; overflow:scroll;" >
    <div style="width:200px; height:50px; background:red;">
        Contents...
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Related question with a very detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408815/fieldset-resizes-wrong-appears-to-have-unremovable-min-width-min-content

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best thing I can come up with is to put 2 nested divs within the fieldset:

```
<fieldset style="width:150px" >
    <div style="width: 150px; overflow-x:scroll;">
        <div style="width:200px; height:50px; background:red;">
            Contents...
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<fieldset style=" width:150px;">
    <div style="width:200px; height:50px; background:red; overflow:scroll;">
        Contents...
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: overflow: scroll would force a scrollbar regardless, overflow: auto may be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

As others [have](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8852602) [already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11516836) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19026006), this is a bug in Firefox: [Bug 261037 - overflow property not implemented on fieldset](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=261037) (reported in 2004, and still not fixed)

Comment: someone told everything is possible but this ain't :p i will eat that bug

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. FF does not allow overflow: hidden on fieldset tags regardless if you use overflow-y or overflow-x. My fix was using '-moz-hidden-unscrollable'. Like this...

```
fieldset{
    overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
}
```

It is a dirty hack but it works.

re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#Values