# Overflow: hidden in firefox 3.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, overflow

I made a form script so that I can always use that if I need a form, but I noticed that when I set for a field the property on overflow hidden it still is visible in Firefox (tested in 3.6).

I saw that still more than 5% of the users look in FF 3.6 so I need to fix it.
I googled it for it but all the fixes they said didn't help me with my bug...

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nbuj/2/) I made a part on the form in JS fiddle, if you can test in chrome, IE 6+ and then FF 3.6 you see the differences (when you click on the checkbox the hidden content should show).

Please can someone help,

Sander

Comment: can you tell us what should we test in different browser, please explain your problem properly so that we help you in the problem, rather than wasting our time in finding the problem.

Comment: but i noticed that when i set for a field the property on overflow hidden it still is visible in FF ( i tested in 3.6 ).

Comment: Why aren't you just using `display:none` rather than hiding overflow?

Comment: Becouse i need The overflow hidden for the slide effect..

Comment: You should still be able to get the slide effect with `display: none;`

Comment: can you show me ( you can edit my code on js friggle )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it is a Mozilla bug that has been going on for over 7 years (reported 2004-09-22):

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=261037

**The problem**

`overflow` is always treated as `overflow: visible` on a `fieldset` when it is assigned a fixed height or width (no matter what you set it as).

**The Workaround**

You could either use `display: none` to hide the fieldset content or if you want to carry on using the `overflow:hidden` approach then you could either change the element from `fieldset` to `div` or nest `fieldset` within another `div` with the property `overflow: hidden`.

**Nested `fieldset` example: http://jsfiddle.net/8nbuj/8/**