# How come overflow:hidden works on a div but not a fieldset in firefox?

Tags: css

I have a fieldset that looks like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <input><label>tada</label>
    <input><label>tada</label>
</fieldset>

fieldset{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 20px;
}

input{
    display: block   
}
```

Js-fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/GWdWy/1/

how come the fieldset shows all it's containing elements, whilst if I change the fieldset to a div:
http://jsfiddle.net/GWdWy/2/

the overflow hidden works.

Comment: I am on Opera 15 and the overflow is hidden for the fieldset also.

Comment: Looks like a browser (firefox?) bug ... It's working in Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you must be on Firefox, if it's that so, than it's a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=261037)

> Bug 261037 - overflow property not implemented on fieldset

---

Workaround: I nested a `div` inside the `fieldset`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GWdWy/7/)

```
fieldset div {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Firefox does not seem to allow overflow: hidden on fieldset tags regardless if you use overflow-y or overflow-x. My fix was using '-moz-hidden-unscrollable'. Like this...

```
fieldset{
    overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
}
```

It is a dirty hack but it works.

re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#Values

Answer (score -2):

The fieldset has padding applied by the default browser css settings.

Use a CSS Reset to make sure the defaults are equalised in all browsers and elements.

Check the most used one - Eric Meyer's reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

in your first fiddle set following css for the Fieldset:

```
fieldset{
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

and this will equalize the display.
For Firefox a workaround can be found here:
[Fieldset contents overflow in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137741/fieldset-contents-overflow-in-firefox)

Comment: Padding does not affect overflow.

Comment: well... check Chrome.

Comment: @mzografski: Mate, are you suggesting this as a fix for Firefox?

Comment: nope, I do not. possible fix I saw here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137741/fieldset-contents-overflow-in-firefox