# Moving the position of the sidebar

Tags: html, css

I have this control on my page which is a `<div style="max-height: X">` inside a `<fieldset>` ([I uploaded on jsfiddle.net the relevant HTML and CSS code](http://jsfiddle.net/WY3dj/14/)).

[image]

As you can see there is a small problem: the area pointed to by the red arrow looks unnaturally empty. The scroll bar should start 9px more above than where it starts now!

Adding `position: relative; top: -9px;` to the div and `padding-top: 9px` to the ul fixes it when you are not scrolled, but once you start scrolling things start to look strange:

[image]

I need both of these:

- There should not be the gap you see in the first image (pointed by the red arrow)
- There should not be the overlapping issue seen in the 3rd image when scrolled down

Comment: your fiddle is fine even when I scroll

Comment: what browser are we talking about? because in webkit it looks good

Comment: My fiddle is not using the `position: relative; top -9px` -- It's the one from the first screenshot, with the unnatural empty space above the scrollbar [EDIT: I updated it to show both]

Comment: div{margin-top: -8px;} ul{padding-top: 5px;}

Comment: @Jawad: this has the same problem when you scroll down though, the "Flag X" text overlaps with the legend

Comment: what happens if u give the overflow: auto; to the <fieldset> instead of the <div>. So we don't need to have the position: relative; top: -9px; for the <div>. That takes care of the gap problem but the overlap problem is still there. However this introduces a problem in FF which aparently has a bug that cause the scrollbars not to show on <fieldset> by using the overflow: auto; property. That can be however taken care of by a hack of display: table-column; - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673346/fieldset-firefox-overflow-css-fix - Still leaves the overlap problem. Are you open to nesting?

Comment: Don't use a fieldset. Fieldsets are ugly stuff when it comes to CSS

Comment: any followup with @Matt Whipple?

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/WY3dj/165/

Just make the legend's position absolute with fieldset's position relative;
Then you can shift your legend with top/margin-top to the top

Answer (score 1):

I hope this works..

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/WY3dj/197/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a visually consistent solution which is probably the best that can be done with HTML/CSS alone (if you're stuck with that look) and can be easily tuned as needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/WY3dj/198/

Answer (score 1):

You can put span below scroll legend making a layer between the 'legend' and 'div', so that it hides 'div' and does not overlap with 'legend' on scroll.

Like this:

```
<fieldset class="scroll">
    <legend>Scroll:</legend>
    **<span class="stopoverlap"></span>**
    <div>
```

Now you can create 'stopoverlap' css like this:

```
.stopoverlap {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    top: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 80%;    
    z-index: 2;
}
```

You also have to define z-index for 'legend' and 'div' under scroll fieldset and their position relative like this:

```
fieldset.scroll div {
    position: relative;
    top: -9px;
    **z-index: 1;**
}
```

and

```
legend {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 5px;
    **position: relative;**
    **z-index : 3;**
}
```

Your scroll will look like:

[image]

Hope this helps

Edit :
Do not put ** in your code as this is just to specify a change or an addition.

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS, replace the value of `top: -9px` and make it as `0px`.

```
fieldset.scroll div
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/WY3dj/10/

Comment: That does not solve "the area pointed to by the red arrow looks unnaturally empty" which is the first problem. The second problem is overlapping.

Comment: Actually right now it doesn't overlap when you scroll right? Did you try giving a `overflow: hidden;` and check?

Comment: Look at the scroolbar which is some distance from the top. As I said "the area pointed to by the red arrow looks unnaturally empty". Think they are mutually iinclusive. If you fix the gap, there will ve overlap and if u fix the overlap there will be gap. I did the same in my comments above but it's not a solution.

Comment: @AndreasBonini and Jawad, still I don't understand. It is rendering perfectly for me!

Comment: I need both of these: •There should not be the gap you see in the first image (pointed by the red arrow)
 •There should not be the overlapping issue seen in the 3rd image when scrolled down

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all styles from fieldset.scroll div

Comment: actually, the problem is being caused by `position: relative`. he just need to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

here, fixed it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/WY3dj/172/

- two nested divs inside the fieldset
- changed your CSS a little bit

**Test 1: Firefox 13**

[image: FF13]

**Test 2: Internet Explorer 9**

[image: IE9]

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/WY3dj/210/

To avoid the overlapping issue, just change the CSS style for following element:

```
legend
{
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add float:left;clear:both for those items, probably will fix lots of issues.